# Set test-framework with gradle init

Tags: java, gradle, junit

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-06-14 14:47:26 UTC
Revision:     989ccc9952b140ee6ab88870e8a12f1b2998369e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_292 (Amazon.com Inc. 25.292-b10)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Do I have a wrong understanding?

Based on the article:
https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html

When creating a multi module project, I'm NOT prompted about the --test-framework when running `gradle init` interactive.

When I specify the parameters from CLI like:
`gradle init --type java-application --dsl groovy --project-name myapp --package myapp --split-project --test-framework junit`

I also get junit-jupiter(Junit5) as test-framework.

buildSrc\src\main\groovy\myapp.java-common-conventions.gradle contains

`testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'`

No change, when I use different --test-framework values.

The generated JUnit examples in the sub-projects always using:
`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

Any hints? Thanks in advance